# Lettuce - DLI recommendation day 1-14 with full spectrum led

Tags: seedlings, lettuce, led

Im looking for a recommendation of the DLI for lettuce in a hydro setup for the first 14 days using a full spectrum led

i would figure it at 8 -12 mol/m2/day what do you think? 
greets